# Will a PowerShell script developed for a Windows 7 run on Win Server 2008 R2?

Tags: powershell, windows-7, windows-server-2008-r2

I have developed a large PowerShell script that has been refined on a Windows 7 64bit box and now I intend to run it on a Windows server 2008 r2. Assuming the PowerShell versions are the same, will there be any major issues with syntax in-between Win 7 and WS 2008 R2?

The script checks a lot of WMI and registry keys like `GWmi Win32_NetworkLoginProfile` and `Get-Itemproperty -Path Registry::HKLM\Software\Microsoft\"Windows NT"\CurrentVersion\winlogon\`

Most PowerShell information is driven towards managing servers so I assume I will be safe, but I want to see if you all can help me learn some lessons before I start banging my head against the wall. 
Thanks

Comment: I assume you really do mean Windows Server 2008 R2 and not Windows Server 2008?  They are completely different versions, and your question as originally posted was inconsistent.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, yup. Included it in my post, but not my tag. My bad. Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no syntax differences between PowerShell on Windows 7 and PowerShell on Windows Server 2008 R2. You may encounter differences in existing services, WMI classes, and registry keys, though.

Answer (score 3):

First you should test it on a virtual machine to see if it works or not.  Then try it on the physical machine. If it doesn't work, modify the code to the specific registry keys.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes. I run PSv4 on both my desktop and one of my servers running 08. Be sure to import the correct modules (if any) and allow for RPC in your firewall (And winrm) if applicable. One note- depending on what you run with the server, commands and functions are only as good as the version you run against (even when invoked). I ran into this problem as I scripted in v4 and environmentally my firm is almost all v2. Enabled -verbose error output and test in virtual machines or a loner laptop. (This is what I did). Good luck!